# How to copy a folder from one one path and paste it to another path using C#?

Tags: c#

The copied original folder should be pasted inside folder named with today's date like "220310"

Like.....

Original folder : c://Org/AbcFolder

Destination folder : D://Dest/220310/AbcFolder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you'd use

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(originalFolder,"*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

to get all files you want to copy, then create target directory by

```
Directory.Create(destinationFolder)
```

and loop over original filenames (in *files*), use *FileInfo* class to get path of original files, and *File.Copy()* to copy files to their new location. 
All of these classes are in *System.IO* namespace.

Answer (score 3):

```
private static bool CopyDirectory(string SourcePath, string DestinationPath, bool overwriteexisting)
        {
            bool ret = true;
            try
            {
                SourcePath = SourcePath.EndsWith(@"\") ? SourcePath : SourcePath + @"\";
                DestinationPath = DestinationPath.EndsWith(@"\") ? DestinationPath : DestinationPath + @"\";

                if (Directory.Exists(SourcePath))
                {
                    if (Directory.Exists(DestinationPath) == false)
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(DestinationPath);

                    foreach (string fls in Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath))
                    {
                        FileInfo flinfo = new FileInfo(fls);
                        flinfo.CopyTo(DestinationPath + flinfo.Name, overwriteexisting);
                    }
                    foreach (string drs in Directory.GetDirectories(SourcePath))
                    {
                        DirectoryInfo drinfo = new DirectoryInfo(drs);
                        if (CopyDirectory(drs, DestinationPath + drinfo.Name, overwriteexisting) == false)
                            ret = false;
                    }
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(DI_Target + "//Database");
                }
                else
                {
                    ret = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ret = false;
            }
            return ret;
        }
```

Comment: looks like this is an extra line `Directory.CreateDirectory(DI_Target + "//Database");`

Answer (score 0):

You can get date time with this :

```
DateTime dtnow = DateTime.Now;
string strDate=dtnow.Day.ToString()+dtnow.Month.ToString()+dtnow.Year.ToString();
```

And for copy the directory to another see this CodeProject article: [Function to copy a directory to another place (nothing fancy)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/copydirectoriesrecursive.aspx)