# How to copy and paste a whole directory to a new path recursively?

Tags: c#, file, directory, copy-paste

I want to move a directory as a copy/paste routine, by keeping its structure as it is. I am not looking only for the files within all subfolders in a directory then copy/paste them (as [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911595/move-all-files-in-subfolders-to-another-folder-using-c-sharp) solution), instead I want to **clone** the whole thing and keep its structure as it is (Tree -> subfolders and files), exactly like a copy and paste routine.

So I found [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490619/how-to-copy-a-folder-from-one-one-path-and-paste-it-to-another-path-using-c) function that copies a folder full of files to a new path:

> Folder -> File(s)

The function behaves as known as the copy/paste routine. It takes SourcePath, DestinationPath and boolean value to OverWriteExisting. Nice and small but too bad it wasn't marked as the actual answer of that question there (recommend a rate).

But what if I want to move a whole directory? In other words, what if I have a folder that has folders of folders of folders of files and etc? And maybe it is unknown the file structure tree size like this:

> Folder -> Folder(s) -> ... -> Folder(s) -> File(s)

I am using the below routine to copy/paste a folder that has folders. But here I know that I only have one level of folders so only one foreach loop is required:

```
foreach (var Folder in DestinationFolder) // here I know that I have only one level of folders to reach the files
{
    CopyDirectory(FolderPath, DestinationPath, false); // use that function to copy the files
}
```

This above function serves this directory structure:

> Folder -> Folder(s) -> File(s)

I tried [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911595/move-all-files-in-subfolders-to-another-folder-using-c-sharp) and it didn't do what I want. I only retrieve all files while it searches all the subfolders. Which is not what I want. I want to keep the subfolders and the original structure as it is. Here I get four files instead of the directory structed as it is, subfolders and their subfolders, subfolders, files. Only four because it removes duplicates which I do not want this to happen because I need all of them.

Here is my current structure(but my question is global to any directory):

> Folder -> Folders -> Folders + Files

Here is what the below code does in the new path:

> NewFolder -> AllFilesFoundInAnySubfolder

```
dialog.FileName = dialog.FileName.Replace(".xml", ""); // get the destination path
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dialog.FileName);

if (dirInfo.Exists == false)
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dialog.FileName);

List<String> EverythingInTheDirectory = Directory
                    .GetFiles(FileStructure.baseSessionPath + "\\" + SelectedSession.Name, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList(); // source

foreach (string file in EverythingInTheDirectory)
{
    FileInfo mFile = new FileInfo(file);
    // to remove name collusion
    if (new FileInfo(dirInfo + "\\" + mFile.Name).Exists == false)
        mFile.MoveTo(dirInfo + "\\" + mFile.Name);
}
```

**How to move the whole directory with unknown size and keep its structure as it is? Not get only the files from a directory and move them!**

Comment: What does `clone` mean in this context and how is it different from copying a directory recursively to another location?  Also, paste some code please.  What have you tried?

Comment: Your linked question has two reopen votes. Be patient, and give it time to be reopened instead of posting **an actual duplicate of that post**. This is not an *instant gratification* site; you don't get answers immediately, and it won't help if you post it again and again.

Comment: People *do* go there. There is a review queue, which is how you got two reopen votes. And the very fact you told  Zuxlx *look in the "question* and you'll see what I tried* show that you already know this is a duplicate. (And to clarify something, *copy/paste* is what a user does in Windows Explorer. Programing solutions don't *copy/paste*; code creates directories and copies files.)

Comment: Duplicating the question in order to link to the original is incorrect behavior. What you *should have done* is edit the original question to improve it, which would have bumped it back to the top of the question list, brought attention to it, and gotten it reopened fairly quickly. (That' exactly what the [help] says you should do, as well.)  What you should do *now* is edit this question to include the code and details from your other question and then delete that other question to remove the clutter.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is an example that will recursively clone a directory to another destination directory.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CloneDirectory(@"C:\SomeRoot", @"C:\SomeOtherRoot");
    }

    private static void CloneDirectory(string root, string dest)
    {
        foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(root))
        {
            //Get the path of the new directory
            var newDirectory = Path.Combine(dest, Path.GetFileName(directory));
            //Create the directory if it doesn't already exist
            Directory.CreateDirectory(newDirectory);
            //Recursively clone the directory
            CloneDirectory(directory, newDirectory);
        }

        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(root))
        {
            File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(dest, Path.GetFileName(file)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for. This did exactly what I wanted. It copies and pastes a folder to a new path. Thanks !

Comment: Me too. Although it's kinda ridiculous, how even modern .net still treats fs-operations :-)

Comment: @hawkstrider I did a variation based on your approach. Thanks again

Comment: No need for the `Directory.Exists` prior to `Directory.CreateDirectory`, as `Directory.CreateDirectory` is no-op if the directory already exists.

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation on code by @hawkstrider .

```
private static void CloneDirectory(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo dest) {
    foreach (var source_subdir in source.EnumerateDirectories()) {
        var target_subdir = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(dest.FullName, source_subdir.Name));
        target_subdir.Create();
        CloneDirectory(source_subdir, target_subdir);
    }

    foreach (var source_file in source.EnumerateFiles()) {
        var target_file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(dest.FullName, source_file.Name));
        source_file.CopyTo(target_file.FullName, true);
    }
}
```

EDIT:
As @EtiennedeMartel correctly states, the `Create()` doesn't need the `Exists` check. [ms-docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.create?view=net-6.0)
Also Enumerations FTW!

Comment: `Create()` is a no-op if the directory already exists, so no need for the `Exists` check. You should also use `EnumerateDirectories()`  and `EnumerateFiles()` for better performance when there are a lot of files to go through (as `GetDirectories()`/`GetFiles()` allocate arrays).